# Why does g.append(l.pop()) return the second half of l but l only has the first half

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

While I was working over one program, I got to see one strange behavior in my code.Here is what I saw.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> g = []
>>> for i in l:
...     g.append(l.pop())
... 
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> g
[8, 7, 6, 5]
>>>
```

The list `g` was supposed to have all the elements of list `l` here! But why did it only take half of the list into account?

**Disclaimer**: I am not trying to copy a list or reverse a list. This was something that I found while working over something else.

Comment: Modifying a list while you are iterating over it is rarely a good idea - you get unexpected results, such as this.

Comment: `l.pop()` returns last element

Comment: everytime you pop you take the last element off of `l` but you are iterating over `l` so when you get to the 4th element there is nothing at that index so the loop ends

Comment: It looks like with every step of the loop the l array grows shorter and only the last 4 positions are 'popped'. I mean that in the 4rth iteration l length is 4 so the loop finishes.

Comment: you can print `l` in the `for` loop. Then you can see changes in the `l` list

Comment: To have all elements, you should do this: `for i in range(len(l)): g.append(l.pop())`

Comment: @Kevin Guan , There was no need for changing the question as I specifically wrote it in disclaimer Disclaimer: I am not trying to copy a list or reverse a list.

Comment: @Kevin Guan, thanks, its better

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal: Ah, don't understand what are you really doing/want when I first edit, but checked the *disclaimer* then ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**YOU SHOULD NORMALLY NOT DO THIS!**
Changing the Iterable you are looping over is not good!

**Explanation:**
As you can see `l.pop()` always takes the last item of `l`
`g.append()` now adds the popped item to the end of `g`
After 4 runs `l` doesnt have any items left.

First Run:

```
i =  v
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
g = [8]
```

Second Run:

```
i =    v
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
g = [8,7]
```

Third Run:

```
i =      v
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
g = [8,7,6]
```

Fourth Run:

```
i =        v
l = [1,2,3,4]
g = [8,7,6,5]
```

Now we are at the end of `l` and we stop the loop

Comment: Ohk, but my questions stands still. Why did it stop at l = [1,2,3,4]? there are still elements in it.

Comment: No they arent, 4 is the last element because the rest have been popped out

Comment: Yes there are elements left (the first 4) but the iterator `i` (i marked it with the little `v`) is at the end of the list.

Comment: @Altoyr Ohk, you mean to say that this is because of that 'iterator' value getting exhausted, and not the list, right?

Comment: Kind of... With every run in our loop the list gets shorter by one element. So after 4 runs - and therefore 4 removed elements - the iterator is at the end of the list and says "Nice, i am finished. Nothing more to do"

Comment: @Altoyr :-) Thanks. I got it finally.

Comment: I am glad I could help